# Python, Implementação Game of Life

Tags: python

Reparei que já existe uma pergunta relacionada com esta questão, porém a minha implementação será diferente.

O código que tenho neste momento é o seguinte:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 125, 125

black = 0,0,0
white = 255,255,255

geracao = 0


pixelarray = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)] 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

def drawPixelAt(x,y, color = black, surface = screen):
    surface.set_at((x,y), color )

def getPixelAt(x,y, surface = screen):
    return surface.get_at((x,y))


def drawPixelArray():
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            if(pixelarray[i][j] == "X"):
                drawPixelAt(j,i)


def printMatrix():

    quadro = "\n"

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            quadro += " " + str(pixelarray[i][j])
        quadro += "\n"

    print(quadro)

def checkNeighbours(x,y):
    vizinhos = 0
    # posicao inicial
    posX = x -1
    posY = y -1



    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):          
            finalX = posX + j
            finalY = posY + i

            if( finalX < 0 ):
                finalX+=1 # avanca para a proxima posicao
            if( finalY < 0 ):
                finalY+=1 # avanca para a proxima posicao

            if( finalX > pixelarray.__len__() -1 or finalY > pixelarray.__len__() -1):
                break # salta este laco, nao e preciso verificar uma coisa que nao existe

            # verifica se a posicao que se esta a verificar nao e o centro
            if( finalX != x or finalY != y):
                #pixelarray[finalY][finalX] = "-"
                # se tem um vizinho
                if(pixelarray[finalY][finalX] == "X"):
                    vizinhos+=1
    #print("Tem {0} vizinhos".format(vizinhos))
    return vizinhos

def makeLife():
    # percorre toda a matriz
    for i in range(pixelarray.__len__()):        
        for j in range(pixelarray.__len__()):
            vizinhos = checkNeighbours(j,i)

            if( pixelarray[i][j] == 0):
                if(vizinhos == 3):
                    pixelarray[i][j] = "X"
            else:
                if( vizinhos < 2):
                    pixelarray[i][j] = 0

                if(vizinhos == 2 or vizinhos == 3):
                    pixelarray[i][j] = "X"

                if(vizinhos > 3):
                    pixelarray[i][j] = 0


    global geracao 
    geracao += 1
    print("{0} Geração".format(geracao))


pixelarray[0][1] = "X"
pixelarray[1][0] = "X"
pixelarray[2][0] = "X"
pixelarray[2][1] = "X"
pixelarray[1][2] = "X"
pixelarray[0][1] = "X"
pixelarray[0][2] = "X"



while 1:
    screen.fill(white)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            #makeLife()
            if event.key == pygame.K_g:
                pygame.display.set_mode(size)
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                    pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)


    makeLife()

    drawPixelArray()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

O código obviamente não está otimizado, o problema é que o resultado esperado não é igual ao apresentado.

Para quêm não conhece o Game of Life baseia-se nas seguintes regras:

Cada célula irá interagir com as suas 8 vizinhas ou seja vertical, horizontal, diagonal. Considere o V como vizinho, e X como a célula que estamos a verificar.

```
V | V | V
V | X | V
V | V | V
```

1. Qualquer célula com menos de 2 vizinhos irá morrer
2. Qualquer célula com 2 ou 3 vizinhos sobrevirá para a proxima geração
3. Qualquer célula viva com mais de 3 vizinhos irá morrer
4. Qualquer celula morta com exactamente 3 vizinhos torna-se viva

[Implementação Online](https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/)

Onde poderá estar o erro no meu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você usa para contar os vizinhos a mesma estrutura de dados que você está modificando para a próxima geração - 
Ao verificar os vizinhos das célular na linha "2", a linha "1" que sua função `checkNeighbors` "enxerga" já foi alterada, e tem células vias e mortas diferentes do que estavam na tela.

Você tem que contar os vizinhos baseados numa "foto" desta geração - e
criar células vivas ou mortas numa estrutura separada.

Você pode usar o `copy.deepcopy`  do módulo `copy` da biblioteca padrão para copiar sua estrutura `pixelArray`. A função que checa os vizinhos tem que usar uma cópia feita antes de você criar as células para a próxima geração.